# Javascript get field ids for URL

Tags: soql, javascript, custom-button, fields, button

I'm trying to replicate the "New" button on a related list.

The only difference is that, if a record of that type already exists, then it simple returns an alert.

Otherwise the "New" activity should proceed as normal.

This is in order to enforce a one-to-one relationship.

So my button javscript looks something like this:

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")}

new_url = "{!URLFOR( $Action.Child__c.New)}";
sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
var query = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM Child__c WHERE Master__c = '{!Master__c.Id}'");
if (!Number(query.size)) window.location.replace(new_url);
else alert('This Master__c already has a Child__c assigned.');
```

This works, but the URL generated does not include information to assign the master record reference. The user would have to guess where they just came from.

I *can* hard code it. Eg:

```
new_url = "{!URLFOR( $Action.Child__c.New, null, [CF00Nm0000000VQvy=Master__c.Name, CF00Nm0000000VQvy_lkid=Master__c.Id])}";
```

But we all know that hard coding Ids is a road to ruin.

So how can I remove those references to field Ids (using standard pages)?

Can I write a SOQL query to pull out field ids?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can use this formula only

```
{!URLFOR( $Action.Child__c.New , null, [saveURL=Master__c.Link, retURL=Master__c.Link, CF00Nm0000000VQvy_lkid=Master__c.Id , CF00Nm0000000VQvy=Master__c.Name])}
```

By giving hard coded ID of the field.

But we can get it through code also in apex, by using toolingAPI. Follow this [link for toolingAPI](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/)

Answer (score 0):

Field Ids are relative to the webpage, you cannot query them. Even if hard coding is bad in this case this is the only route to go.

If you are worried about things breaking in the future I would say use a custom setting create a map of the field ID and field name and reference it in your formula.

Refer this doc on how to access the custom settings in your formula.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_accessing.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Field ids aren't relative to the webpage. They're part of the CustomField object. You can see the id if you view a custom field though setup. The Id is part of the URL. You can see the same id used to populate fields when creating a New custom object.

Comment: as far as i know you cannot query field id, there is an idea  / alternate solution related to this issue : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gM7mAAE